Locally transforming a color code into two surface codes
I've heard before that there are 2d-local unitary operations that transform color code stabilizers into two sets of surface code stabilizers. Globally this would presumably do things like transform a color code into a folded surface code, or a toric color code into two toric surface codes.
What are the 2d-local operations that do this? Give an actual 2d-local circuit.

Not an explicit circuit, but section IIB of https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.02065 might interest you

The transformation is to pick one of the three colors, and apply this circuit to every hexagon of that color:

Here's that same transformation but as a ZX graph:

Note that some of the surface code stabilizer generators come from adjacent or overlapping pairs of the color code stabilizer generators, instead of it being exactly one-to-one w.r.t. the generators.
Here is a crumble circuit showing the transformation from end to end:

